# How to import org.apache in android studio?

Tags: android

I downloaded `components-client-android-4.3.5.1.zip` file. But no jar file can import. How to import all java file in android Studio. please tell me detailed steps. Thank your help. p.s I am a beginner so I am not good at programming. Thank your help.

Comment: extract your .zip file and check .jar file exist or not

Comment: You need only one step. Add `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'` in your build.gradle file. No need to download zip or add jar files.

Comment: jar is not found.
I import success.Thank your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HttpClient** is not supported any more in sdk 23. You have to use URLConnection or downgrade to sdk 22 **(compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0')**

If you need sdk 23, add this to your gradle:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

You also may try to use OkHttp instead

and also if you want to use this dependecy..

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5'
```

then also change class path version.. so you can overcome ambiguity problem.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
```

Comment: Thank your help.I imported success.Excuse me why change class path?
If the HttpClient is older,should I change other class to use?

Comment: older version of apache lib is run fine in older classpath that's why.. otherwise you face ambiguity problem, you are not able to make sign apk cause ambiguilty.

Comment: my best recommendation is use  this useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

Comment: Thank you your help.I know your mean.

Comment: If my answer work for you.. plz approve it..  and you are welcome

Comment: Sure.The approve is green hook?

Answer (score 0):

[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB5Zs.jpg)

Write The Code To In "build.gradle" File

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
```

Comment: I import success .Thank your help

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your build.gradle file

`compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'`

No jar file require.

Comment: Yes,I import success .Thank your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to build.gradle (Module:app) `compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.2'`

Comment: I import success .Thank your help